# Write a surjective function for the sets $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B = \{a,b,c\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to write a surjective function for the sets in the question, but I'm having a little bit of trouble.

Would this be ok? $f(A) = (1\mapsto a, 2\mapsto b, 3\mapsto c, 4\mapsto a)$?

Comment: Yes, that looks perfectly good.

Comment: @lulu, Thanks! How would I write it in correct notation?

Comment: write letter or no. in between $2$ dollar sign.

Comment: $d$?!!! but you donot have $d$ in $B$

Comment: You could just write $1\mapsto a, 2\mapsto b, 3\mapsto c, 4\mapsto d$.  Writing $f(A)=$ before that is not standard notation.  Notice that $\mapsto$ is different from $\to$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @AndréNicolas : I wonder if I introduced a typo.  I recall the question originally saying $4\mapsto a$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The OP's edited version is now right, so I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

$1\mapsto a$

$ 2\mapsto b$

$ 3\mapsto c$

$ 4\mapsto a$

Answer (score 0):

Number of surjective function from $A = \left\{1,2,3,4\right\}$ to $B = \left\{a,b,c\right\}$ is equivalent

to fill $3$ different boxes $\boxed{a}\;\;,\boxed{b}\;\;,\boxed{c}$ with $4$ balls with lebel $1,2,3,4$ such that each box contain at least one ball

$\bullet $ Distribution of balls in boxes $\left\{2,1,1\right\}$

So total no. of ways $\displaystyle = \binom{4}{2}\times \binom{2}{1}\times \binom{1}{1}\times \frac{3!}{2!} = 6\times 2\times 1\times 3 = 36$

Comment: thank you for the clear answer, but I'm just trying to show one example of a surjective function

Comment: Your function doesnt go from A to B. You dont have a $d$ element in $B$.

Comment: Where you wrote "No. of surjective functions", I saw "No." and thought you were answering the question by saying "No."  Writing out the word number would have obviated that.